# Eclipse Error: Error parsing ...\android-22\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

Recently, I upgraded my android-SDK to **Android M (API 22, MNC Preview)**. After that, every project reported errors when Eclipse was opened.

The error of **logcat** and of **a popup window** says:

> Error: Error parsing
>   ...\sdk\system-images\android-22\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'd:skin'. No child element is expected at this point

I thought there was something wrong in **devices.xml**. So I went to check this file.

What I found was: many lines like the picture below:

[image]

But all **xml** tags are well-formatted. Then I couldn't understand.

So could somebody explain this to me?
What's wrong with my **Eclispe** or my **Andrid-SDK**?
What happened when I was updating SDK?

Any tips will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As @Elenasys said, it's a good idea if you don't use Android Wear Images. If you don't want to delete images, all will work well although. In fact, I give up Eclipse and stop using it.

Comment: Same thing happens with Luna (4.4.2) based Eclipse ADT and Android API level 23. The marked answer (uninstalling Android Wear images) helps.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had the same error message:

> Error: Error Parsing
>   C:\Android\sdk\system-images\android-22\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml
>   Invalid content was found starting with element 'd:Skin'. No child
>   element is expected at this point.

There´s a problem with the packages of android wear of the API 22, so my solution was deleting this packages:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. It resolve the error by removing this two packages.

Answer (score 3):

I deleted the android-wear ARM EABL v7a System-Image and android-wear Intel x86 Atom System-Image from SDK. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Open SDK manager from eclipse and select 1. android-wear ARM EABL v7a System-Image and 2. android-wear Intel x86 Atom System-Image for API version 22 and delete it.

If anyone face similar problem for other API version just select those packages from respective API version and delete.
Just it. Solved your problem and enjoy!!!

Answer (score 0):

Look for the lines ..../d:skin> in file devices.hml, comment out or delete these lines will eliminate the error messages.